# Are Lifshitz and Berestetskii right in this case?

Tags: dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

In the [Quantum electrodynamics](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Tpk-lqyr3GoC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=charge%20conjugation%20majorana%20%20lifshitz&source=bl&ots=yokDyfOAxC&sig=oqSfh2MAyTAGaj3Pj1pg9J6ikJs&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=P8zyUr-yO5HIswbG0oCACg&ved=0CGoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=charge%20conjugation%20majorana%20%20lifshitz&f=false) book (look at the problem) its authors Lifshitz and Berestetskei claim that operator of charge conjugation $\hat {C} = -\alpha_{2}$ in Majorana basis transforms as $\hat {C}^{M} = \alpha_{2}$. Here (they started from the [standart (Dirac) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Dirac_basis) of the gamma-matrices) 
$$
\alpha_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma_{y}\\ \sigma_{y} & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \beta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},
$$ 
$$
\hat {C}^{M} = \hat {U}^{+} \hat {C} \hat {U}, \quad \hat {U} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha_{2} + \beta ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sigma_{y}\\ \sigma_{y} & -1\end{pmatrix} = \hat {U}^{+}.
$$
I tried to get their result, but I only got
$$
\hat {C}^{M} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sigma_{y}\\ \sigma_{y} & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma_{y}\\ \sigma_{y} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sigma_{y}\\ \sigma_{y} & -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},
$$
because $\sigma_{y}^{2} = 1$.

Where is the mistake?

**An edit**.

I found the mistake. I used the wrong definition of transformation of charge conjugation operator under unitary spinor transformation. The correct one is $\hat {C}^{'} = \hat {U}\hat {C}\hat {U}^{T}$.

Comment: Where did you get the transformation matrix? Is this a well known result to switch between representations of the Gamma matrices?

Comment: @JeffDror : this matrix is given in the text of the problem linked above and connects Dirac and Majorana basis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Other_representations ). The matrix can be derived from considerations of imaginarity of all of gamma-matrices in Majorana representation. I think that this is the well-known result for switching representations, since I saw it in some modern articles, like here, http://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/2/4/1776 .

Comment: It may be better to answer your own question if you feel it's solved, and accept the answer. This will make it more useful for those having similar problem and looking for a solution.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but would anyone mind sharing a reference where the correct transformation of $\hat{C}$ is explained? I would have also mindlessly assumed that $\hat{C}'=\hat{U}\hat{C}\hat{U}^{\dagger}$ and thus would have made the same mistake @AndrewMcAddams made if I hadn't found this post.